# JSON Data is going in request parameter(Instead of String) in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I am using fetch mehtod to send and api call but request parameter is going in JSON format insted of String. this is my code plz correct me where i did mistake

```
export function RestApi(data) {
  let BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api/login";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(BaseUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        resolve(responseJson);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

---

```
this.state = {
  username: "",
  password: ""
};

RestApi(this.state).then(result => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little bit unclear, if you want to send as plain text you can set headers content-type as below.

```
fetch(BaseUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  }
});
```

---

**EDIT**

actually, sending JSON string should always use `application/json`

```
fetch(BaseUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Comment: my question is, I am sending Api request using Above mentioned method but when I am trying to get the request parameter in laravel, I am not able to get the request parameter. To get the request paramter I've to use this function

$request = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 
$request['username']
but this is not proper way, normally we use $request->username

Comment: change content type to `application/json` like this`"Content-Type": "application/json"`

Comment: right now I am getting json request without setting Content-type : application/json in header which I dont want normal request